# iPhone SDK: Image Capture Landscape Mode

Tags: iphone

I want to allow my users to draw a picture on their screen in landscape mode.

Upon button being pressed, that image should be stored locally on the device.

I am using this code example below which works vertically
http://www.ipodtouchfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024

My problem is that I'm trying to adjust the code for landscape mode  with a smaller drawing area but it's not working. I am not sure why?

There seems to be three areas that involve the bounds that the user may draw in. I've tried changing the size but that doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

```
Orignally:

viewDidLoad:
drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
drawImage.frame = self.view.frame;

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
...
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
...
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Are you having trouble with the user drawing on the screen part or with the capturing the image and storing it part?  In what way is your code "not working"?  That is: (a) What did you expect to happen? and (b) What happened, instead?

Comment: Can you show the portion of code you use to adjust for landscape mode with a smaller drawing area? Perhaps you are not doing this correctly.

Comment: "drawImage.frame = self.view.frame;" -> are you sure that's what you want to do? you generally set child.frame = self.view.bounds

Answer (score 0):

If you are intended to have only landscape view. Then add the following code to the example:-

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        return YES;
    else 
        return NO;
}
```

and go to project properties and set device orientation to **Landscape Left** and **Landscape Right**

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I am also using that code for drawing and when I am switching to landscape mode I am giving again frame for our drawimage. Or the view you are using for drawing. If you are giving your `UIView` class from xib class then its better to set landscape mode frame from there.

And yes, one thing if make some drawing in portrait mode and switching to landscape mode then you have to adjust its lastpoint and currentpoints as per your area.